# How to get unicode of punjabi text?

Tags: android, unicode

I am developing an android application In which i want Punjabi text on my view After searching a lot from the internet i got a link (http://forums.waheguroo.com/index.php?/topic/15835-anyone-has-new-cool-punjabi-fonts-for-dtp/). In this link on the bottom there is some text written in it *(kI ikqoN hQilKq pMjwbI PoNt vI iml skdy hn jI)* when i copy paste this in my application it gives me proper Punjabi text. But i have also a punjabi text file when i copy that text it does not give me proper view. I think that my Punjabi text is not converted to unicode. Can you give me a solution by which i can convert my Punjabi text like (kI ikqoN hQilKq pMjwbI PoNt vI iml skdy hn jI) so i can View proper Punjabi text on my emulator.

Comment: The text in your question is Punjabi?? I have never seen Punjabi like that!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to identify what script and encoding is used by your original string and after this you'll be able to convert it using [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)